# Keep newline characters from copy-pasting for JSON Validation

Tags: python, html, json

Problem : newline characters not kept by HTML form after pasting.

I'm developping an app that does JSON format validation check. I want to paste the JSON string in the form, then thave the app check its validity using the json module from Python.

Should there be any error, the function :

```
json.loads(jsonstring)
```

returns the line, and the column where the error is occuring. I need to retrieve the line and the number. However, pasting in my form doesn't keep the newlines, hence everything is on line 1 ...

What shall I do so that pasting in the form keeps the newlines ?

Comment: What input field are you using? A `<textarea wrap="soft">` should preserve your newlines as submitted.

Comment: Interesting, the json.loads can read the newline charactor, can you check that its actually present in the string `assert '\n' in jsonstring`

Comment: which method are you using, GET or POST?

Comment: @lanzz : Thanks so much, the form kept the newlines, and the json.loads function gave me the right line ! 
samy.vilar : I'm using POST.
I'm using the example from http://json.org/example.html - The form kept all the newline characters and the indentation spaces. But when I display my form data back in my template, the spaces are gone. How can I preserve them ?

Comment: Response to my comment : to keep the spaces in HTML, we need to add a CSS class :

    <div style="white-space:PRE">
        {{ string_with_spaces }}
    </div>

Comment: Since you find a solution, can you post your answer, and accept it.

Comment: Would be nice if you could write your solution in an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to that question is to specify the option "wrap=soft" in the textarea tag. Which gives the following :

```
<textarea "wrap=soft">
This is the text that I pasted after I copied the output of my JSON validation function. \n 
with newlines characters that are gonna be seen after I pasted it in the text field.
</textarea>
```